# SAPUI5: Issue in getting datetime values from HANA db to Chart

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to get the datetime values and aggregated

response time from hana database to a bar chart.
I have done the aggregation in .xsodata file as :

```
{
     service namespace "excercise.services" {

     "ABC"."XYZ" as "sample" key generate local "Key" 

      aggregates always(SUM of "respti" )  ;

 }

 }
```

I am getting aggregated response time values but it is not

getting synchronized with the respective date values .

Please help me on getting the correct values.

Here is the view.js file:

```
{
var oModel = sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel('.xsodata/', false);
var oDataset = new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset({
    dimensions: [{
            axis: 1,
            name: 'Time Instance',
            value: {
                path: "ts",
                formatter: function(fValue) {
                    jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat");
                    var oDateFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
                    return oDateFormat.format(new Date(fValue));
                }
            },
        },
    ],
    measures: [{
        name: 'Response Time',
        value: '{respti}'
    }],
    data: {
        path: "/sample",
        filters: [
          new sap.ui.model.Filter("inst", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, "instance")
         ],
        parameters: {
            select: 'ts,respti'
        },
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try

```
    dimensions: [{
        axis: 1,
        name: 'Time Instance',
        value: {
            path: "ts",
            formatter: function(fValue) {
                if(fValue){
                   jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat");
                   var oDateFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
                   return oDateFormat.format(new Date(fValue));
                } else {
                   return fValue;
                }

            }
        },
    }],
```

what is the format of respti, you may want to format that also, using a D3 formatter maybe simplest way